# Normalize length of cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array of length 3 and I want to make a `for` loop with another cell array with length of `6` , so how can I add extra 3 cells for the first array in order to make the 2 cell arrays equal and to use my `for` loop in MATLAB?

For example, with 2 inputs:

```
type = { '12' '62' '5' };
colour = {'re' 'green' 'yellow' 'brown' 'blue' 'black'};

for i = 1:length(colour)
    if isequal(colour(i), type(:))
        result(i) = type(i);
    else
    end
end
```

I need to make the `type` cell array with the same size with `colour` cell array (I think I have to add extra 3 empty cells in side the `type` cell array).

Comment: Can you please include some code, your inputs, and the desired output?

Comment: please check the edited question above...  :)

Comment: I have a strong hunch this is a classical case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please, can tell us what your end goal is?

Comment: I think I found the answer by my self :                          type=[type cell(length(colour)-length(type))]..thank u anyway :):)

Answer (score 2):

I have to address several issues in your code first:

1. If you use a cell array, you must use curly braces (`{}`) to extract elements from it. Instead of writing `colour(i)` you should be writing `colour{i}`.
2. This is not a problem, but it's a matter of good practice. If you don't need to handle the `else` part of the `if` statement, don't write it at all.
3. Preallocate memory so that arrays don't grow inside the loop (it slows down the program). Specifically, add the line  `result = cell(size(colour));` before the `for` loop.
4. Your [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) logic is flawed. Practically, it would always return `false` because `colour{1}` is one element and `type{:}` is many.
5. According to your example, `types` contain numbers and `colours` letters, although they are both strings. Does it make sense to compare the two?

Now, regarding your question, it's up to you to decide how the `for` loop runs. Since you don't mention what you want to achieve (you rather ask how you want to achieve something without saying what exactly), I cannot say what your `for` loop should look like, if necessary at all. Maybe you meant to use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) instead of `isequal`? If so, the fixed code can look like this:

```
result = cell(size(colour));
for i = 1:length(colour)
    if ismember(colour{i}, type)
        result{i} = type{i};
    end
end
```

or shorter, like this:

```
result = cell(size(colour));
[found, idx] = ismember(colour, type);
result(found) = type{idx(found)}
```

If you provide more details, maybe I can refine my answer so that it helps you more.